# visual studio 2012 update 3 compiler bug - not calling dtor

Tags: visual-c++

I believe I've found a somewhat obscure but scary bug in the Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 C++ compiler. I found it while writing unit tests using gtest. The tests started showing memory leaks, and after investigating the problem seemed to reduce to a bug in the compiler.

I submitted the issue to Microsoft:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794722/parameter-dtor-not-called-when-overloaded-operator-involved-in-return

In the past I've mistakenly called "compiler bug" on more of my own bugs than I care to admit. So I thought I'd post the question here in case anyone wants to attempt to reproduce the problem themselves. If I can be pointed towards a mistake of my own in this code, that would be extremely helpful! I'm really hoping it's not actually the case that the VC++ compiler fails to call destructors in the following program.

Note that the faulty behavior occurs with the optimizer disabled, so it's not an optimizer bug.

I tried this code in gcc 4.2.1 (i686-apple-darwin11) and it behaves as expected.

Here's the code for the single source file in the project:

```
#include <string>

int instance_count= 0;

class c {
public:
    c( std::string s ) : m_s(s) { ++instance_count; }
    c( const c& other ) : m_s(other.m_s) { ++instance_count; }
    ~c() {--instance_count;}
private:
    std::string m_s;
};

class d {
public:
    d() {}
    void operator=(int) {}
};

void f( c c_ ) {
    try {}
    catch(...) { return d() = 5; }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    c instance("leak");
    f(instance);
    return instance_count == 1 ? 0 : -1;
}
```

To compile it in Visual Studio 2012 Update 3:

1. File -> New -> Project..., select Win32 Console Application, click OK then click Finish
2. Build -> Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform -> New..., select x64, click OK
3. Replace the contents of the main .cpp file with the above code
4. Either add #include "stdafx.h" to the top of the file or turn off precompiler headers
5. Run the program, note that the exit code is -1, I expect it to be 0. This seems to reproduce in both 32-bit and 64-bit builds, although I was focusing on 64-bit.
6. Comment out the try/catch blocks in f(), note that the exit code becomes 0. I don't see why this change should affect the exit code since the catch() block isn't even executing.

Comment: It is too heavily optimized to make the call.  Looks like the code optimizer is thrown off by f() being optimized and no longer taking the argument.  Wait for the feedback report follow-up.

Comment: Actually this happens with the optimizer disabled - I edited the question to include that important info.

Comment: Maybe not related, but I'm not sure `return d() = 5;` should compile in the first place. You are effectively returning the `void` value produced by your assignment operator. The caller does return `void` itself, but using `return` in this context looks strange to me.

Comment: That is indeed part of the puzzle.  Remove the *return* keyword and the problem disappears.  It is a codegen bug, it calculates the wrong address to continue to after the try{}, skipping the ~c destructor call for the argument.  Looks like it is too confounded by the catch clause code.

Comment: I agree that it looks cryptic. It's actually from a FAIL() statement in Google's gtest unit testing framework. They use this overloaded operator=() in a helper class for some reason that's not clear to me. I do think it's valid C++ though. I remember back in msvc6 days when returning a void expression from a function that returns void wouldn't compile and it drove me crazy!

Comment: Connect link is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an issue in codegen. The dissassembly shows the following for function f.

With return statement -

```
    try { }
002039B8  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],1  
002039BC  jmp         f+6Eh (02039DEh)  
    catch(...) { return d() = 5; }
002039BE  push        5  
002039C0  lea         ecx,[ebp-0D5h]  
002039C6  call        d::d (0201474h)  
002039CB  mov         ecx,eax  
002039CD  call        d::operator= (0201479h)  
002039D2  mov         eax,2039E7h  
002039D7  ret  
002039D8  mov         eax,2039DEh  
002039DD  ret  
$LN4:
002039DE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
002039E5  jmp         $LN8+0Fh (02039F6h)  
$LN8:
002039E7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFFFFFFFh  
002039EE  lea         ecx,[c_]  
002039F1  call        c::~c (020101Eh)  
}
```

Notice the jump f+6Eh(02039DEh) for dissassembly of try block. This jumps to

```
002039DE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
002039E5  jmp         $LN8+0Fh (02039F6h)
```

which totally skips the call to destructor. One more thing to observe is that the call to destructor is *before* the closing brace ('}').

If we take a look at the code without return statement,

```
    try { }
013839B8  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],1  
013839BC  jmp         f+68h (013839D8h)  
    catch(...) { /*return*/ d() = 5; }
013839BE  push        5  
013839C0  lea         ecx,[ebp-0D5h]  
013839C6  call        d::d (01381474h)  
013839CB  mov         ecx,eax  
013839CD  call        d::operator= (01381479h)  
013839D2  mov         eax,13839E1h  
013839D7  ret  
013839D8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
013839DF  jmp         $LN8+7h (013839E8h)  
$LN8:
013839E1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
}
013839E8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFFFFFFFh  
013839EF  lea         ecx,[c_]  
013839F2  call        c::~c (0138101Eh)
```

Here, the call to destructor is *after* the brace ('}').

Comment: Thanks for the complete analysis of the bug. It seems like a pretty serious one to me, but the VC++ compiler team has decided not to fix this bug at this time (you can see their comments at the MSDN link in my question)!